# Using curly brackets in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have an array of ID's used to execute mysqli queries in a foreach loop (the below code is just an example - the array will contain more than 50+ elements/ID's). For each array element/ID I query an array which I then include in a compData array. However, I am unsure of how to dynamically define the arrays in the foreach loop. I would very much appreciate if you can check whether I am using ${$val} correctly in the below or if something else is wrong. Thanks.

```
  $idArray  = array(
    "List1",
    "List2",
  );

  $compData = array();
  foreach($idArray as $val) {
    $sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE ID = {$val}");
    ${$val} = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
      For ($n = 1; $n <= $CI_NOYEARS; $n++){
        ${$val}['data'][] = $r[$n]; 
      }
    }
    $compData[{$val}] = ${$val}
  }

  foreach($compData['List1'] as $result) {
    For ($n = 0; $n <= $CI_NOYEARS; $n++){
      echo $result[$n];
    }
  }
```

The above code does not work and does not echo any data from the $compData array. Below is an example that works just fine where I execute the code using the ID's directly.

```
  $sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE ID = 'List1'");
  $List1 = array();
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    For ($n = 1; $n <= $CI_NOYEARS; $n++){
        $List1['data'][] = $r[$n];
    }
  }

  $companyData = array();
  $companyData['List1'] = $List1;

  foreach($compData['List1'] as $result) {
    For ($n = 0; $n <= $CI_NOYEARS; $n++){
      echo $result[$n];
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is rarely any use for variable variables that can't be solved with an associative array.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: My problem is that the data is not being added to the $compData array. The echo does not return anything. I am fairly sure that there is an error in the     $compData[{$val}] = ${$val . "Array"} line.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure your `echo` doesn't return anything because you're burying your data many levels deep. Your loops at the end there don't account for the fact that you've put things under the `data` element of the array, for example.

Comment: I have tried to add more explanation and included a piece of code that works as intended. Hopefully this will clarify what the issue is?

Comment: What's with the `for` loop over the database columns?

Comment: As you say the for loop is meant to loop over columns instead of rows. This is due to the structure of the mysql table which is quite complex and imported from a csv file.

Comment: It would make more sense to select the columns you want instead of `SELECT *` if that's the case. Regardless, my answer is updated to only include those columns between 1 and `$CI_NOYEARS`

Comment: The reason I choose not to do that is because I have a lot of different tables and the number of columns vary for each. As such, I use a 'column-counter' which is $CI_NOYEARS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tough figuring out what your goal is based on the code you provided, but it seems far more complicated than it needs to be. I think what I've got here will replicate your desired output.

You should also be using prepared statements; they are safer, and take a lot of the overhead out of database queries when you're going to be repeating the same query multiple times. I've implemented them here.

```
$idArray = ["List1", "List2"];
$sth     = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE ID = ?");

foreach($idArray as $val) {
    $data = [];
    $sth->bind_param("s", $val);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->get_result();
    while ($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $data = array_merge($data, array_splice($r, 1, $CI_NOYEARS));
    }
    $compData[$val]["data"] = $data;
}

foreach($compData["List1"]["data"] as $result) {
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: This works pretty much perfectly! Thank you very much. However, for some reason the echo includes the "List1" ID name as the first entry. For instance the echo currently is: "List1, 1, 2, 3..". Would you be able to tell me how I can prevent that?

Comment: Unless it's in the database, my code isn't outputting that value anywhere. Try `print_r($compData)` to see what's actually in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using that curly-brace notation at all when you're just copying it over into a multidimensional compData array anyway? Why not just directly put the data into the array:

```
for ($n = 1; $n <= $CI_NOYEARS; $n++) {
    $compdata[$val]['data'][] = $r[$n];
}
```

(You'll also need to declare it as an array at the top level of the `foreach` of course.)

Side note: I would suggest not interpolating data directly into your query string like that, and instead using bound parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php It's much more secure.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I've tried your solution but my echo of the results in $compData['List1'] for instance doesn't return anything. The code above works just fine when I do execute it for every ID but due to the large amounts of ID's I just wanted to do this dynamic by using an array and foreach statement instead? I hope this makes sense. I will have a look at the link you provided as well.

Comment: Did you declare the value as an array before the code I gave you? If so, and it's still not working, I'd suggest printing the value of `$val` inside that loop, so you can make sure there is, in fact, a "List1" in there. (I'd also suggest using either print_r or var_dump when outputting arrays, instead of echo, since those will give you the full values of the array entries.)